# Changing the textsize of the selected value in the exchange

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the textsize of the selected value when the user changes the selected value.

Example:

[image]

All good, but when we change to something bigger like:

[image]

You see that the text got out of the select element, I do not want to change the size of the selected element according to the size of the selected value.
I want to change the selected value's text size to fit in the element.

Is there a way to do that in javascript?

Comment: Give some id to select and access it by "document.getElementById('idname')..style.fontSize = "12px".

Comment: But plz always post some code to help you better

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try something like this, but this would make your page clumsy as the font sizes are not uniform throughout.

```html
<html>
    <select style="width: 150px;" id="dropdown">
     <option>Todas</option>
        <option>Sesporte - contrasxyz</option>
        <option>Sesporte - contrasxyz - todas</option>
    </select>
    <script>
    var activity = document.getElementById("dropdown");
    function start(){
    activity.addEventListener("change",addActivityItem,false);
    }

    function addActivityItem(){
          //option is selected
          if (activity.value.length > 10)
          {
           activity.style.fontSize = "8px";
          }
          else
          {
           activity.style.fontSize = "16px";
          }
    }

    window.addEventListener("load", start, false);
    </script>
    </html>
```

However you can remove the 'style' for the 'select' tag, so that the page automatically fits all the sizes within the dropdown.

```html
<html>
<select>
 <option>Todas</option>
    <option>Sesporte - contrasxyz</option>
    <option>Sesporte - contrasxyz - todas</option>
</select>
</html>
```